# Powershell - Display multiple columns from hash tables next to each other

Tags: arrays, powershell, formatting, hashtable, tabular

My powershell code:

```
$h1 = [ordered]@{
    "item1" = "command1"
    "item2" = "command2"
    "item3" = "command3"
    "item4" = "command4"
    "item5" = "command5"
}

$h2 = [ordered]@{
    "col1" = "result1"
    "col2" = "result2"
}

$h1.GetEnumerator() | Format-Table @{
    Label = "Item";
    Expression = { $_.Key }
}, @{
    Label = "Command";
    Expression = { $_.Value }
}

$h2.GetEnumerator() | Format-Table @{
    Label = "Column";
    Expression = { $_.Key }
}, @{
    Label = "Result";
    Expression = { $_.Value }
}
```

Output

```
Item  Command
----  -------
item1 command1
item2 command2
item3 command3
item4 command4
item5 command5


Column Result
------ ------
col1   resul1
col2   resul2
```

### Desired Output

```
Item  Command  Column Result
----  -------  ------ ------
item1 command1 col1   resul1
item2 command2 col2   resul2
item3 command3
item4 command4
item5 command5
```

I'm trying to display two hash tables next to each other.  Is it possible with 2 hash tables?  Or maybe I should use two arrays?

Basically I just want to display multiple columns, but with uneven data, as shown in my desired output.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following using custom objects:

```
$index = 0
$output = $h1.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{'Item' = $_.key; 'Command' = $_.value}
}
$h2.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
    $output[$index++] | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'column' = $_.key;'result' = $_.value}
}
$output
```

Comment: Nothing is displayed.  Tried both PowerShell 5.1 and 7.0.2.  I even added a `PAUSE` to see if any errors are produced, but nothing.

Comment: Did you call $output to output it in the command line? When I did it produced the expected result.

Comment: @Kulantan That did it.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Kulantan How could I format the table, by adjusting the width of one of the columns?  I've tried piping `$output` to `Format-Table`, and adding a calculated property which includes a width, but it didn't work: `$output | Format-Table -Property Item, @{ Label = "Command"; Expression = { $_.Command }; Width = 20 }, Column, Result`

Comment: Never mind.  I figured it out.  I have to set the width for all columns.