# Powershell - Display contents of two tables next to each other

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to display information for administrators processing user changes to easily see what changes are being made to certain fields in Active Directory users. I've written a PowerShell script to process these changes, but I'm having trouble formatting the output for the administrators who are running the script. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62438728/powershell-display-multiple-columns-from-hash-tables-next-to-each-other) for a similar, but different problem.

My code:

```
$output = [pscustomobject]@{'UserName' = $user.samAccountName; 'FirstName' = $user.GivenName;'LastName' = $user.Surname;'DisplayName' = $user.DisplayName;'UPN' = $user.UserPrincipalName;'E-Mail_Address' = $user.proxyAddresses;'Title' = $user.Title;'Office' = $user.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName;'Dept' = $user.Department;}
$output[$index++] | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewUserName' = $samAccountName; 'NewFirstName' = $firstName;'NewLastName' = $lastname;'NewDisplayName' = $displayName;'NewUPN' = $UPN;'NewE-Mail_Address' = $SMTP1;'NewTitle' = $Title;'Newoffice' = $office;'NewDept' = $department;}
$output
```

Output:

```
UserName          : FirstLast
FirstName         : First
LastName          : Last
DisplayName       : First Last
UPN               : FirstLast@company.com
E-Mail_Address    : SMTP:FirstLast@company.com
Title             : CEO
Office            : HQ
Dept              : Executives
NewDept           : Maintenance
NewE-Mail_Address : SMTP:FirstLast@company.com
NewOffice         : The Dump
NewFirstName      : First
NewLastName       : Last
NewUserName       : FirstLast
NewDisplayName    : First Last
NewUPN            : FirstLast@company.com
NewTitle          : Trash Collector
```

Desired Output:

```
UserName          : FirstLast                     NewUserName       : FirstLast
FirstName         : First                         NewFirstName      : First
LastName          : Last                          NewLastName       : Last
DisplayName       : First Last                    NewDisplayName    : First Last
UPN               : FirstLast@company.com         NewUPN            : FirstLast@company.com
E-Mail_Address    : SMTP:FirstLast@company.com    NewE-Mail_Address : SMTP:FirstLast@company.com
Title             : CEO                           NewTitle          : Trash Collector
Office            : HQ                            Newoffice         : The Dump
Dept              : Executives                    NewDept           : Maintenance
```

Comment: The output you’re seeing is from ```Format-List``` rather than ```Format-Table``` - unfortunately there’s no built-in options to specify multiple columns in the output. If you’re wedded to the idea of this format you’re going to have find a third party cmdlet / module or roll your own I’m afraid :-(.

Comment: You can add both to an array, stringify the properties and values, then list both in their own column. This'll make it seem like a side by side comparison is being done

Comment: @AbrahamZinala. That sounds promising. Do you have an example you could provide as an answer?

Comment: @McKenning, sure, let me get home and I'll post one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below will create the two Format-List outputs next to eachother.
Because more than likely this will not fit the width of the console screen, the output is captured first and output using `Out-String` with a high number for parameter `-Width`.
Like this, you can also save to text file.

```
$outputOld = [pscustomobject]@{
                'UserName' = $user.samAccountName; 'FirstName' = $user.GivenName;
                'LastName' = $user.Surname;'DisplayName' = $user.DisplayName;
                'UPN' = $user.UserPrincipalName;'E-Mail_Address' = $user.proxyAddresses;
                'Title' = $user.Title;'Office' = $user.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName;
                'Dept' = $user.Department}
$outputNew = [pscustomobject]@{
                'NewUserName' = $samAccountName; 'NewFirstName' = $firstName;
                'NewLastName' = $lastname;'NewDisplayName' = $displayName;'NewUPN' = $UPN;
                'NewE-Mail_Address' = $SMTP1;'NewTitle' = $Title;'Newoffice' = $office;
                'NewDept' = $department}

# capture the Format-List output of each object and split into a string array
$outLeft  = @(($outputOld | Format-List | Out-String) -split '\r?\n')
$outRight = @(($outputNew | Format-List | Out-String) -split '\r?\n')

# determine the maximum length of each string in the list that goes to the left
$maxLength = ($outLeft | Measure-Object -Property Length -Maximum).Maximum
# get the maximum number of lines
$maxLines  = [math]::Max($outLeft.Count, $outRight.Count)

# collect the combined output
$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxLines; $i++) {
    $left  = if ($i -lt $outLeft.Count) { "{0,-$maxLength}" -f $outLeft[$i] } else { ' ' * $maxLength }
    $right = if ($i -lt $outRight.Count) { $outRight[$i] } else {''}
    ('{0}    {1}' -f $left, $right).TrimEnd()
}

# display on screen
$result | Out-String -Width 1000

# save to text file
$result | Out-String -Width 1000 | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\output.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you, Theo. I was able to use this as described. I'm especially grateful that you took the time to format the width of each table dynamically. That makes things look so much better!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't produce *exactly* the same character-by-character output as you're after, but it *does* produce something *similar* using the built-in formatting methods without lots of stringifying of values.

First, set up some test data, which would need a small change to your sample code to generate as two objects, instead of your combined `$output` variable:

```
$oldValues = [pscustomobject] [ordered] @{
    "UserName"          = "FirstLast"
    "FirstName"         = "First"
    "LastName"          = "Last"
    "DisplayName"       = "First Last"
    "UPN"               = "FirstLast@company.com"
    "E-Mail_Address"    = "SMTP:FirstLast@company.com"
    "Title"             = "CEO"
    "Office"            = "HQ"
    "Dept"              = "Executives"
};

$newValues = [pscustomobject] [ordered] @{
    "NewDept"           = "Maintenance"
    "NewE-Mail_Address" = "SMTP:FirstLast@company.com"
    "NewOffice"         = "The Dump"
    "NewFirstName"      = "First"
    "NewLastName"       = "Last"
    "NewUserName"       = "FirstLast"
    "NewDisplayName"    = "First Last"
    "NewUPN"            = "FirstLast@company.com"
    "NewTitle"          = "Trash Collector"
};
```

Next, we map the variables into an array of `PropertyName, OldValue, NewValue` objects:

```
$rows = $oldValues.psobject.properties `
    | foreach-object {
        $property = $_;
        [pscustomobject] [ordered] @{
            "PropertyName" = $property.Name
            "OldValue"     = $property.Value
            "NewValue"     = $newValues.("New" + $property.Name) 
        }
    };
```

And then we can format it using the built-in cmdlets:

```
$rows | format-table

# PropertyName   OldValue                   NewValue
# ------------   --------                   --------
# UserName       FirstLast                  FirstLast
# FirstName      First                      First
# LastName       Last                       Last
# DisplayName    First Last                 First Last
# UPN            FirstLast@company.com      FirstLast@company.com
# E-Mail_Address SMTP:FirstLast@company.com SMTP:FirstLast@company.com
# Title          CEO                        Trash Collector
# Office         HQ                         The Dump
# Dept           Executives                 Maintenance
```

The nice thing is you can adjust things like column widths, word wrap, etc just using the `Format-Table` parameters, or even use `Format-List` instead:

```
$rows | format-list

# ... etc ...
#
# PropertyName : Title
# OldValue     : CEO
# NewValue     : Trash Collector
#
# PropertyName : Office
# OldValue     : HQ
# NewValue     : The Dump
#
# ... etc ...
```

And you can filter it to show just *changed* values:

```
$rows | where-object { $_.NewValue -ne $_.OldValue } | format-table

# PropertyName OldValue   NewValue
# ------------ --------   --------
# Title        CEO        Trash Collector
# Office       HQ         The Dump
# Dept         Executives Maintenance
```

It relies on the property names being in the format "`Xyz` -> `NewXyz`", but there's ways around that if it's not true in all cases...

Comment: Thank you, Mclayton. While this wasn't what I was looking for, it has some elements that are useful to me in other ways. I appreciate that it displays this in a comparison table.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ANSI ESCAPE codes to apply decorations. This sample is based in pscustomobject with all values, but you can create two pscustomobject to make clear the code.

Notes:

Change ESC to $([char]27) or `e in Ps6 (thank you Mr. mclayton)

I prefer use Add-Member item per item.

Tested with PowerShell 5.1 ($PSVersionTable command).

```
$output = [pscustomobject]@{'UserName' = 'User1'; 'FirstName' = '$user.GivenName';'LastName' = '$user.Surname';'DisplayName' = '$user.DisplayName';'UPN' = '$user.UserPrincipalName';'E-Mail_Address' = '$user.proxyAddresses';'Title' = '$user.Title';'Office' = '$user.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName';'Dept' = '$user.Department';}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewUserName' = 'User2'}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewFirstName' = '$firstName'}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewLastName' = '$lastname'}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewDisplayName' = '$displayName'}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewUPN' = '$UPN'}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewE-Mail_Address' = '$SMTP1'}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewTitle' = '$Title'}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'Newoffice' = '$office'}
$output | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{'NewDept' = '$department'}
    
# Counter for column 1 and column 2
$Counter =0
$Counter1 =0

# Temporally variables
$Text 
$Label

# Do the magic
foreach( $property in $output.psobject.properties.name )
{
    
if ( $Counter -lt 9 )
{
    $Counter = $Counter +1
    $Text = $output.$property
    $Label = $property
    echo "ESC[$Counter;1H $Label : $Text "
    
} else
{
    $Counter1 = $Counter1 +1
    $Text = $output.$property
    $Label = $property
    echo "ESC[$Counter1;60H $Label :  $Text "
    } 
    
}

#Move to end
echo "ESC[20;1H  "
```

Result

[image]

Other ANSI commands

[image]

Happy coding my friends.

Comment: Nice. :-) As a side-note, I found this only worked properly when invoking the code from a *.ps1 and not pasting it interactively into a ```PS>``` prompt - when I tied it interactively it output everything in a single list in the right-hand column. Also worth noting you can insert an ESC character with, e.g. ```"$([char]27)"``` in PS <=v6, or simply ```"`e"``` in PS > v6...

Comment: Thank you, Carlos! This is an element of PS I didn't know existed and so you get a +! for me for sharing that. Great find!

Comment: You welcome Mr. McKenning and Thank you Mr. mclayton and others, that is the the secret of great teamwork.